# Rails 4: Unable to retrieve specific attributes of a model that `belongs_to` two other models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

So I have an `Active` model (think of it as a User) that uses Devise for authentication. I also have a `Rushee` model (you can think of them as products), and on each Rushee's profile page, I give Actives the option to leave a `Rusheepost` (think of them as product reviews).

I'll post some of my code first, then will describe the problem.

Here are my models:

```
class Rushee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rusheeposts, dependent: :destroy

class Active < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rusheeposts, dependent: :destroy

class Rusheepost < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :active
    belongs_to :rushee
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :actives, :path_prefix => 'my'
resources :actives, only: [:index, :show]

resources :rushees, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :rusheeposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

RusheepostsController

```
before_action :authenticate_active!

def create
    @rushee = Rushee.find(params[:rushee_id])
    @rusheepost = @rushee.rusheeposts.build(rusheepost_params)
    @rusheepost.active = current_active

    if @rusheepost.save
        flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
        redirect_to @rushee

    else
        flash[:error] = "There was an error with your comment; please try again."
        redirect_to @rushee
    end
end

private

def rusheepost_params
    params.require(:rusheepost).permit(:content)
end
```

RusheesController (I only want signed in actives to be able to view rushees)

```
class RusheesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_active!

    def show
        @rushee = Rushee.find(params[:id])
        @rusheeposts = @rushee.rusheeposts
        @rusheepost = @rushee.rusheeposts.build if active_signed_in?
    end

    def index
        @rushees = Rushee.all
    end

end
```

`show` view for Rushees

```
<% provide(:title, @rushee.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= @rushee.name %>
        <%= @rushee.email %>
            <%= @rushee.grade %>
            <%= @rushee.major %>
      </h1>

      <section>
        <%= render 'shared/rusheepost_form' %>
      </section>

    </section>
  </aside>

  <!-- Displays the rusheeposts that are associated with the current rushee -->
  <div class="span8">
    <% if @rushee.rusheeposts.any? %>
      <h3>Comments (<%= @rusheeposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="rusheeposts">
         <%= render @rusheeposts %>
      </ol>
    <% end %>
  </div>

</div>
```

_rusheepost_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@rushee, @rusheepost]) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new comment..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

_rusheepost.html.erb

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= rusheepost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(rusheepost.created_at) %> ago by: <%= rusheepost.active.name %>
  </span>
</li>
```

**The Problem**

The `_rusheepost.html.erb` partial does not render. The `content` renders correctly every time. However, if I put `Posted <%= rusheepost.created_at %>`, it renders to: `Posted 2013-12-25 21:08:19 UTC`. However, `Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(rusheepost.created_at) %>` gets me a `undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass` error.

Furthermore, just putting `Posted by: <%= rusheepost.active.name %>` gets me the same nilclass error. Putting `Posted by: <%= rusheepost.active %>`, however, gets me: `Posted by: #<Active:0x007ff3466108a0>`.

Strangely enough, everything works if I try to retrieve a rusheepost's rushee attribute. For instance, `Posted by: <%= rusheepost.rushee %>` yields `Posted by: #<Rushee:0x007fa6681a56d8>`. Similarly, `Posted by: <%= rusheepost.rushee.name %>` yields `Posted by: Theodora Willms III`, the name of the rushee who the post is associated with (and whose page I am on.) Obviously though, this isn't the functionality I want -- I want each post to display who *posted* it, not who the post is about.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening? Maybe I didn't initialize something correctly? I am failing to see why I cannot retrieve attributes of a rusheepost's active, but I can retrieve attributes of a rusheepost's rushee. I also must note that before I added the form to create new rusheeposts, I had the resources in my `routes.rb` listed on top of each other (not nested), and **everything** rendered correctly, including this: `Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(rusheepost.created_at) %> by: <%= rusheepost.active.name %>`. After I nested the resources and changed my controllers to reflect the nesting, the problems I describe appeared.

Thanks, and sorry about the (very) long post. Let me know if there's any more information/code I can post that would help.

**EDIT**: I also must note that if I reset the database with no rusheeposts, then log in to my site, post on a rushee's page, and then go into `rails console` and type `Rusheepost.first.active.name`, I *do* in fact get the name of the Active that I was signed in as, which makes this all the more puzzling...

Answer (score 0):

You've got `=>` instead of `%>` terminating your Ruby code in your `_rusheepost.html.erb` file.

Comment: Sorry, just a typo -- it still gives me the `NilClass` error with `Posted by: <%= rusheepost.active.name %>`.

Comment: Are you sure the `nil` error isn't coming from `time_ago_in_words(rusheepost.active.created_at)` instead of `time_ago_in_words(rusheepost.created_at)`? No offense, but the typo you had suggests you aren't copy/pasting from the actual failed source.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure. Just putting `Posted by: <%= rusheepost.active.name %>` (and not including anything about `time_ago_in_words`) yields the `NilClass` error as well...

Comment: I know you answered that you solved it, but to clarify I wasn't asking about the significance of the presence of `time_ago_in_words`, but the distinction between `rusheepost.created_at` and `rusheepost.active.created_at`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Needed to put `@rusheeposts = @rushee.rusheeposts.all` instead of `@rusheeposts = @rushee.rusheeposts` in my `RusheesController`, and this fixed the problem.

Comment: This doesn't explain what you saw, since the former object should respond identically to the latter object with respect to the operations you're performing. Further, `all` is deprecated on an ActiveRecord `Relation`, so this isn't something you want to retain.